# Is there a possibility that two different polynomials have same polynomial orbit on Siegel Disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

As we know, if $x \in F(P)$ is on a Siegel disk, of which $F(P)$ represents the Fatou set, then the closure of the set {$x,P(x),P(P(x))...$} will form a simple closed curve on the complex plane.
Is there a possibility that two different polynomials form the same curve on the complex plane?